# web view dismiss all controllers on selection on image gallery or camera access in swift 4

Tags: webview, controller, camera, gallery, dismiss

I have strange problem in my iOS app, there is one gif controller which is my root controller and after that navigate controller and then home controller(root controller -> Navigation controller -> home controller). only from web view which have image access from gallery when I started app from gif controller then when select action sheet it dismissed all controller till root controller and gif running and when I stated from navigation screen then all things working fine.

Comment: Please include more information, including the related code snippets in your question. Otherwise, it would be difficult to know what is going wrong.

Comment: there is only simple web view code all thing happening through url when we upload image from web view then after action sheet all controllers dismissed to root controller. it not only happening from web view.

Comment: Did you solve this ? @vartikakrishna

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this piece of code:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
  open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
  }
}
```

It only works with the Photo Library. Still trying to figure out how to do it for the camera as well and not just the library